# Knockout JS inconsistent parameter passing

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, data-binding

I was passing parameters to components in Knockout JS and came across this behavior. Is this intended?

When I pass testParam1 based on a conditional check against an expression having observable, it returns the parameter wrapped up as a computed observable function and not value.
However, it works as expected for conditional check against an expression not having any observables.

```js
ko.components.register('parent', {
  viewModel: function(params) {
    this.test = ko.observable(true);
    ko.components.register('child', {
      viewModel: function(params) {
        console.log('testParam1:',params.testParam1);
        console.log('testParam2:',params.testParam2);
      },
      template: '<div>Child Component</div>'
    });
  },
  template: '<div>Parent Component</div><child params="testParam1: test() ? \'y\' : \'n\', testParam2: 1 ? \'y\' : \'n\'"></child>'
});

ko.applyBindings();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<parent></parent>
```

Comment: When you usen observable in you parameter, knockout wraps parameter value as computed observable to support future updates, if you don't use observables knockout pass direct value because update are not possible

Comment: That makes sense. Stupid me. Thanks!